# Pgadmin4 in geonode configuration - error 502 nginx docker [RESOLVED]

Tags: docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy, pgadmin-4

Hi I'm trying to add pgadmin4 to the docker-compose of the geonode open source software, using nginx  Letsencrypt already plugged in as a service and postgresql/postgis.

1. I add service pgadmin4 in docker-compose.yml
   https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

```
pgadmin4:
    container_name: pgadmin4
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    depends_on:
     - geonode
     - db
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: root
 #   ports:
 #     - "5050:80"
```

i try to set port to 5050:80 or 5050:5050 or empty and i have the same error.

These are the reference files that I have left unchanged

https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode/blob/master/scripts/docker/nginx/nginx.conf.envsubst
https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode/blob/master/scripts/docker/nginx/nginx.https.available.conf.envsubst
https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode/blob/master/scripts/docker/nginx/geonode.conf.envsubst

2. I went into the nginx shell
   docker compose exec geonode sh
3. and added the location /pgadmin4 in geonode.conf (sites-enabled)

```
(example geoserver)

location /geoserver {
       set $upstream geoserver:8080;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host; 
        proxy_pass http://$upstream/;
        proxy_redirect off;

}

location /pgadmin4 {
       set $upstream pgadmin4:5050;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://$upstream/;
        proxy_redirect off;

}
```

4. I restarted nginx
   docker exec -it nginx4geonode nginx -s reload

I get a 502 Bad Gateway error if I try to reach domain.cloud/pgadmin4.
The error is nginx
connect() failed (111 connection refused) while connecting to upstream client xxxx server: domain.cloud request GET /pgadmin4 HTTP/1.1 upstream http://172.18.0.7:5050/pgadmin4 host: "domain.cloud"

Geonode on domain.cloud works perfectly and geoserver too.

Thanks for any advice.

---

The solution is

```
pgadmin4:
    container_name: pgadmin4
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    depends_on:
     - geonode
     - db
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: root
     SCRIPT_NAME: /pgadmin4
    port:
      - "5050:80"
     expose:
      - "5050"

location /pgadmin4 {
       set $upstream pgadmin4:80;
      
        proxy_set_header X-Script-Name /pgadmin4
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://$upstream/;
        proxy_redirect off;

}
```